# Duplicated desktop, ubuntu 14.04 in VMWare

Tags: xorg, display, vmware

I am operating Ubuntu 14.04 through VMWare Player version 6.0.3 on a Windows 7 OS.

Yesterday, I installed GIMP through the Ubuntu software center. After opening a couple of jpegs to do some simple manipulation, Ubuntu froze. Nothing I tried could allow me to close programs or even react to a mouse click or key so I suspended the VM hoping that it would correct the problem upon resumption.

When I did resume, the issue of freezing had indeed stopped BUT now my desktop within Ubuntu is duplicated across the screen, the "second" version overlapping the first enough that in order to manipulate anything I have to drag it right and left to reach the links and buttons.

I uninstalled GIMP and have rebooted the machine several times. I've done some web research and some previous versions of Ubuntu seem to have had this issue related to the xorg.conf file. I don't have a xorg.conf on this system and while I have found an X11 directory, the file that looks like a configuration: XvMCConfig doesn't appear to be something editable. I've tried altering the screen size in the display settings manager but that's just made smaller or larger versions of the same problem.

I've run a different virtual machine from VMWare to make sure it wasn't a problem at that level and the other VM displays fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Tim, OK looking to do the update, I saw that it has been upgrading automatically. Currently running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: I've updated VMWare Player but still have the screen duplication. I noticed this during startup: piix4_smbus controller SMBus not enabled. It may be that this error had always displayed on startup, however.

Comment: Well, I just wound up finding an old version of the virtual machine. That seems to be working ok. I just have to rebuild whatever software fixes I'd done in the past six months or so.